# How to make this scroll 120px above the content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, smooth-scrolling

When I apply this script, it goes to the link but I want it to go 120px above the content it is linked to.

Here is the code:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    // Add smooth scrolling to all links
    $("a").on('click', function(event) {

    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== 0) {
      // Prevent default anchor click behavior
      event.preventDefault();

      // Store hash
      var hash = this.hash;

      // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
      // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 800, function(){

        // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    } // End if
  });
});
</script>
```

**EDIT #02**

Here is my HTML, CSS and Java for those who are wondering:

https://codepen.io/crosso_7/pen/WYegpY

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add relevant HTML to the snippet I made you. Please select jQuery as framework too. Click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53084493/edit) and scroll down and click Edit above snippet

Comment: So why not `scrollTop: ($(hash).offset().top-120)+"px"`?

Comment: @mplungjan axpers, it does not work when I change and replace the code because it snaps back at the same position when using my original code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is `window.location.hash = hash;` after `animate` it do second action which is same with default action. Replace it with `history.pushState(null, null, hash);` to rewrite the url history and add hash

```
$('html, body').animate({
  scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top - 120
}, 800, function() {

  // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
  //window.location.hash = hash;
  history.pushState(null, null, hash);
});
```

Comment: You are amazing bud.

Answer (score 1):

Simply subtract the amount of pixels from your calculation.

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
    // Add smooth scrolling to all links
    $("a").on('click', function(event) {

    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== 0) {
      // Prevent default anchor click behavior
      event.preventDefault();

      // Store hash
      var hash = this.hash;

      // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
      // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top -120
      }, 800, function(){

        // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    } // End if
  });
});
```

Comment: This too, does not work. when I click ones it's jumpes back, you need to click twice before it does it's thing.
(your code does work, buts you need to click twice)